# select latest record from MySql view

Tags: mysql

I have a `sql view` which looks like below data

```
leadId  status  statusTime
--------------------------
1361    new     2017-06-12 11:57:33
1358    new     2017-06-12 11:20:46
1358    warm    2017-06-12 11:21:20
1358    closed  2017-06-12 11:56:57
```

You can see that the `leadId 1358` has `3 lead status` and the last one is `latest`. So I want the record like below table

```
leadId  status  statusTime
--------------------------
1361    new     2017-06-12 11:57:33
1358    closed  2017-06-12 11:56:57
```

how can I achieve this ?? thanks

Comment: Try this:  select max(lead_id),status  statusTime from table Group by lead_id,status  statusTime

Comment: max(lead_id) may not correct @MuhammadMuazzam he need retrieve base on statusTime

Comment: yes, your query is pulling the oldest record. but I need latest record based on statusTime

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

One canonical way of handling this in MySQL is to join your view to a subquery which identifies the most recent status times for each `leadId`.  This join filters off all records except those most recent records.

```
SELECT v1.*
FROM yourView v1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT leadId, MAX(statusTime) AS max_status_time
    FROM yourView
    GROUP BY leadId
) v2
    ON v1.leadId     = v2.leadId AND
       v1.statusTime = v2.max_status_time
```

An alternative to this would be to use a correlated subquery, but that probably would not perform as well as what has been given above.

## Demo

Comment: this makes the query very slow. I have to wait for 4-5 minutes to get the results

Comment: My guess is that the slowness is due to the view, rather than my query strategy, which is what probably should be used here.  You can try running the query directly on the table rather than the view.  Also, how many records does your view/table have?

Comment: There are lots of data in the table (approx 3000 data), and I can't run the query on table, I have to run on view because many data are gathered there from another 2 tables.

Comment: Without seeing all of the queries going into the view, I'm afraid I can't comment further.  I would recommend adding appropriate indices to the query which generates the view.  This should hopefully speed up the answer I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select leadId,status,statusTime 
from your_view
where (leadId,statusTime) 
     IN (select leadId,MAX(statusTime) as maxStatusTime
         from your_view
         GROUP BY leadId)
```

First find the entries with latest `statusTime` then use it to get the details